# アプリ一覧の最下部にボタンを追加したい

Tags: android, android-layout

androidでアプリ一覧を作成しており、最下部にアプリ一覧とは別のボタンを配置しようとしています。
ところがボタンを配置したところ、一覧のすべてにボタンが重なって付与されてしまいます。
（リスト一覧の部品の一部としてボタンが扱われているように見えます。）
リスト一覧とは別に、最下部にボタンを配置する方法はありますでしょうか？3日くらい悩んでいるので、助けて頂ければ嬉しいです。

（xml内では、RelativeLayout(横)内にImageView、TextView、TextView、LinearLayoutを定義し、LinearLayout内にボタンを定義しております。
アプリ一覧のリストは、listViewとArrayAdapterを使用して実装しております。）

### LancherApp.java

```java
public class LancherApp extends Activity {

//
private ArrayList<String> items = null;
//
private ApplicationListAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate (bundle);
    requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
    // create String Arraylist.
    List<AppData> appList = new ArrayList<AppData>();
    // create PackageManager.
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    // make application list in your device has already installed.
    final List<ApplicationInfo> installedAppList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo app : installedAppList) {
        AppData data = new AppData();
        data.label = app.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
        data.icon = app.loadIcon(packageManager);
        data.name = app.packageName;
        appList.add (data);
    }

    final ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    adapter = new ApplicationListAdapter(this, appList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setContentView(listView);
}

    // private Adapter Class indicates label and icon of application.
    private static class ApplicationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppData> {
    //
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ApplicationListAdapter (Context context, List<AppData> dataList) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        addAll(dataList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        holder.textLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.packageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    //
    final AppData data = getItem(position);
    //
        holder.textLabel.setText(data.label);
        holder.imageIcon.setImageDrawable(data.icon);
        holder.packageName.setText(data.name);

    return convertView;
    }
}

// private class for storing application data.
private static class AppData {
    String label;
    Drawable icon;
    String name;
}

// private class ViewHolder.
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textLabel;
    ImageView imageIcon;
    TextView packageName;
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: おそらくご自身で推測されている通りだと思います。記載されてませんが、`ApplicationListAdapter`でactivity_main.xmlのレイアウトを使用してリスト１件分の`View`を生成されているのではないでしょうか。`Activity`と`Adapter`でそれぞれ分けてレイアウトファイルを作成すれば良いかと思います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。知識不足で申し訳ないのですが、1画面に複数のレイアウトファイルを指定する方法はありますでしょうか？includeと書いて1つのxmlにもう一方のxmlをインポートするというやり方でしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

ListView の一つの要素のレイアウトと、画面全体のレイアウトは、別々の XML ファイルに書きます。

例えば、イメージとして、

ListView の一つの要素のレイアウトは、

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ImageView/>
  <TextView/>
  <TextView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

画面全体のレイアウトは、

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ListView/>
  <Button/>
</LinearLayout>
```

のようにします。

Java のコードの方では、

- setContentView() は画面全体のレイアウト
- Adapter では一つの要素のレイアウト

をそれぞれ指定します。

ListView は画面全体のレイアウトの方で作ってありますので、`new ListView(this)` で作る必要はありません。`findViewById()` で取得してください。

結果として、以下のような感じになると思います (コンパイルすら試していませんのでご注意ください)。

Java コード: LancherApp.java:

```
public class LancherApp extends Activity {

    //
    private ArrayList<String> items = null;
    //
    private ApplicationListAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate (bundle);
        requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        // create String Arraylist.
        List<AppData> appList = new ArrayList<AppData>();
        // create PackageManager.
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        // make application list in your device has already installed.
        final List<ApplicationInfo> installedAppList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo app : installedAppList) {
            AppData data = new AppData();
            data.label = app.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
            data.icon = app.loadIcon(packageManager);
            data.name = app.packageName;
            appList.add (data);
        }

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ApplicationListAdapter(this, appList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // private Adapter Class indicates label and icon of application.
    private static class ApplicationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppData> {
        //
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ApplicationListAdapter (Context context, List<AppData> dataList) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            addAll(dataList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder.textLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                holder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.packageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //
            final AppData data = getItem(position);
            //
            holder.textLabel.setText(data.label);
            holder.imageIcon.setImageDrawable(data.icon);
            holder.packageName.setText(data.name);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    // private class for storing application data.
    private static class AppData {
        String label;
        Drawable icon;
        String name;
    }

    // private class ViewHolder.
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textLabel;
        ImageView imageIcon;
        TextView packageName;
    }
}
```

画面全体のレイアウト: activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

一つの要素のレイアウト: list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ＞masmさん

コードの修正箇所まで教えて下さりありがとうございます！
ご指摘の通りやってみました。リスト一覧の表示までは出来ますが、ボタンが見えなくなってしまいました。。
（activity_main.xmlのボタン、layout_height="0"ではコンパイルが通らなかったので
"1dp"や"wrap_content"でやってみました。）

Comment: @りょーrr すみません、ListView の layout_height は `0` でなくて `0dp` です。回答を修正しました。